# "window.history.pushState" and retrieve these URL-parameters using PHP $_GET

Tags: php, jquery

For an index.php file (and other related php-files) I need to use values for screenheight (sh) and screenwidth (sw). When a user enters the index.php as an url then using window.history.pushState will refresh the url (not the page) and shows the screenheight and width.

How can I access these URL-parametervalues as PHP GET-parameters......$_GET['sw'] / $_GET['sh']??

```
window.history.pushState({sw:$(window).width(),sh:$(window).height()}, "Test page", "?sw=" + $(window).width() + "&sh=" + ($(window).height()));

var param = history.state; // param['sw']     /    param['sh']
```

Comment: Why dont you to send the height and width using jquery get (ajax) instead? It is much easier

Comment: Ok......I'll look into that!
At the moment I use "window.location.href" to reload page if no screenwidth and height are present in the URL.